# In copula modeling for time series data, why do we need to fit ARIMA/GARCH and then work on standardized residulas.?

Tags: time-series, garch, copula, arima

I have read that for standard copula modeling, you can get empirical cdf of data and use it for copulas. But for time series data, we must first fit ARIMA/GARCH, get standardized residuals, and only then start copula modeling. What is the reason for this using standardized residuals and not directly the time series data for the copula modeling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the univariate time series follow ARMA+GARCH, why do we not model them as i.i.d.? After all, it would make our job easier. The answer is, inference based on an i.i.d. assumption will be wrong and forecasts suboptimal when the series follow ARMA+GARCH (or contain autocorrelations and autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity that are better approximated by ARMA+GARCH than by i.i.d.). In finance, using copulas on standardized residuals from ARMA+GARCH may often make a better approximation than using copulas on raw data.

And just in case you might wonder what use is a copula model on standardized residuals when you want a model for the original data: the entire model (ARMA+GARCH+copula) is actually for the original data, so you can make inference and forecasts for the original data.